# Counting record that matches conditions in django

Tags: django, count

For my project I need to count distinct products that have a balance larger than $100.
The model kinda looks like this:

```
class Client(models.Model):
  ...

class Product(models.Model):
  ...

class ClientProduct(models.Model):
  client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product)

class Balance(models.Model):
  clientproduct = models.ForeignKey(ClientProduct)
  balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

but I'm clueless... And other related questions here in SO don't really address this scenario...
Please help.

Comment: What is the relation between a Balance and a Product?

Comment: They are not related, but once a client buys a product, they are assigned a unique clientProduct ID. I use that ID to track the balances. I realized I forgot to type this relationship on my code. edited my post to include the ClientProduct foreign key on the Balance class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like something like this should work:

```
balances_over_100 = Products.objects.filter(clientproduct__balance__gte=100)
balances_over_100.count()
```

Comment: I had no idea you could filter using the classes for which the class serve as foreign key! Thanks.

btw, this works too and it saves one line  Products.objects.filter(clientprodduct__balance__balance__gt=100).count()

Comment: Yep, I was being more explicit to help out ... glad this fixed your issue!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking to sum all Balances grouped by ClientProduct.product, and filter products who have a balance sum greater than $100. Something like:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Product.objects.annotate(
              balance_sum=Sum('clientproduct__balance')
         ).filter(balance_sum__gte=100)
```

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for, but I learned something nonetheless. Thanks for the reply